# Converting lot of Json dictionaries in .json file to a list of json record

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a .json file with with 448 records. The file is the format like this -
**2 Records as sample data**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a5faa4f8b91277fde0212b1"),
    "geo_accession" : [ 
        "GSE86910"
    ],
    "title" : [ 
        "RNA-seq transcriptonal profiling in human primary adult erythroid progenitor celression"
    ],
    "summary" : [ 
        "The developing erythroid cerythroid cells, and performed RNA-seq transcriptional profiling analysis."
    ],
    "num_samples" : 6,
    "overall_design" : [ 
        "Human primary adult erythroblasts were generated ex vivo from extracted for RNA-seq analysis."
    ],
    "samples" : {
        "GSM2310252" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shNT-rep1",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2310253" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shNT-rep2",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2310254" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shTFAM-rep1",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2310255" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shTFAM-rep2",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2310256" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shPHB2-rep1",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2310257" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shPHB2-rep2",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        }
    },
    "geo_signal" : {}
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a5faa4f8b91277fde0212b6"),
    "geo_accession" : [ 
        "GSE83592"
    ],
    "title" : [ 
        "JQ1 +/- Vemurafenib in BRAF mutant melanoma (A375)"
    ],
    "summary" : [ 
        "The apoptotic genes significantly down-regulated."
    ],
    "num_samples" : 2,
    "overall_design" : [ 
        "dsf"
    ],
    "samples" : {
        "GSM2210563" : {
            "title" : "16L",
            "source_name_ch1" : "A375 cell line",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2210564" : {
            "title" : "16R",
            "source_name_ch1" : "A375 cell line",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
            },
    "geo_signal" : {}
}
```

Now I am totally fine with this format but apparently json.load doesn't work on this format and gives tihs error

```
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1
```

Is this any way to convert all this to a list of record in json format like this

```
    [
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a5faa4f8b91277fde0212b1"),
    "geo_accession" : [ 
        "GSE86910"
    ],
    "title" : [ 
        "RNA-seq transcriptonal profiling in human primary adult erythroid progenitor celression"
    ],
    "summary" : [ 
        "The developing erythroid cerythroid cells, and performed RNA-seq transcriptional profiling analysis."
    ],
    "num_samples" : 6,
    "overall_design" : [ 
        "Human primary adult erythroblasts were generated ex vivo from extracted for RNA-seq analysis."
    ],
    "samples" : {
        "GSM2310252" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shNT-rep1",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2310253" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shNT-rep2",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2310254" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shTFAM-rep1",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2310255" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shTFAM-rep2",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2310256" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shPHB2-rep1",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2310257" : {
            "title" : "RNAseq_A5-ProE-shPHB2-rep2",
            "treatment_protocol_ch1" : "NA",
            "source_name_ch1" : "Human primary adult proerythroblasts (ProEs)",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        }
    },
    "geo_signal" : {}
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a5faa4f8b91277fde0212b6"),
    "geo_accession" : [ 
        "GSE83592"
    ],
    "title" : [ 
        "JQ1 +/- Vemurafenib in BRAF mutant melanoma (A375)"
    ],
    "summary" : [ 
        "The apoptotic genes significantly down-regulated."
    ],
    "num_samples" : 2,
    "overall_design" : [ 
        "dsf"
    ],
    "samples" : {
        "GSM2210563" : {
            "title" : "16L",
            "source_name_ch1" : "A375 cell line",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
        "GSM2210564" : {
            "title" : "16R",
            "source_name_ch1" : "A375 cell line",
            "organism_ch1" : "Homo sapiens",
            "library_strategy" : "RNA-Seq"
        },
            },
    "geo_signal" : {}
}
    ]
```

Preferably using python. Thanks.

Comment: Neither of your examples are valid json.

Comment: @jordanm I know they don't matter. What I am trying to say is there are json records and I want them as list of json records.

Comment: Better way will be to update the code responsible for creating this file to write the valid json

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri actually I am getting this file from the mongo servers so there is no way to change the format of the file obtained.

Comment: @l0n3_w01f it looks like you just shoved two seperate documents into the same file. If you need it to be an array of objects, you should do that at query/file write time.

Comment: Also, your second example is missing a ",".

Comment: @jordanm okay I hear you, but this is how the file is received from the mongo servers that I am using, if I export the whole collection from mongo server to json data.\

Comment: I'm still very skeptical that it doesn't have something with the way you are exporting or writing the file.

Comment: @jordanm ok but what if this is the file that I have, Can I still convert this file to a list of mongo records?

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression processing as a valid JSON.

```
import re
import json
def replaceFun(match):
    return match.group(1)
f=open("file/test.json","r")
str=f.read()
pattern=re.compile(r",\s*}",re.M)
newstr=pattern.sub(r"\n}",str)
pattern=re.compile(r"ObjectId\((.+)\)",re.M)
newstr=pattern.sub(replaceFun,newstr)
f.close()
newdict=json.loads(newstr)
for v in newdict:
    print(v)
```